# vector of lists + iterator CPP

Tags: c++, list, vector, iterator

I am trying to implement insertion of a word into a chained hashtable.
The problem is I am trying to insert a object that has 2 fileds and I need access to one with an iterator. The problem seems to happen with the iterator `it` as the code doesn't work from the for cycle. I also overloaded the `operator==` in `Vocabolo.cpp` to make it work for my case.

I also have a problem the size of the vector, can I use a define? It seems not. Any advices please?

I declared my vector of list + iterator in the header file as :

```
vector<list<Vocabolo>> hash;
list<Vocabolo>::iterator it;
```

this is part of the class Vocabolo :

```
class Vocabolo {
public:
    Vocabolo();
    ~Vocabolo();

    void setVocabolo(Vocabolo);
    string getVocabolo();

    bool operator== (Vocabolo);

    string termine;
    string tipo;
};
```

this is the overloaded method operator==:

```
bool Vocabolo::operator== (Vocabolo x) {
    return getVocabolo() == x.termine;
}
```

the method that is not working!

```
bool HashV::Insert(Vocabolo nuovo) {
    key = this->HashUniversale(nuovo.termine);

    for (it = this->hash[key].begin(); it != this->hash[key].end(); it++)
        if (it->termine == nuovo.termine)
            return false;
        else {
            hash[key].push_back(nuovo);
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: You're pushing new elements into your `hash` while simultaneously iterating over it. Adding new elements into a vector can cause it to realocate its memory and invalidate the previous iterators.

Comment: Note that your loop will be run at most once, as you return immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using std::find_if instead:

```
auto itVoca = std::find_if(this->hash[key].begin(), this->hash[key].end(), [nuovo](const string& str)
{
    return str != nuovo.termine;
});

bool found = itVoca != this->hash[key].end();
if(found ) hash[key].push_back(nuovo);

return found;
```

Comment: No problem! The "vector subscript out of range" error you have is probably due to the value of "Key" which exceeds the range of the vector.

Comment: I gave no range to the vector yet. I mean I just declared it and I thought the push_back would add one more element to it starting from 0. the function is :

`
int Hash::HashUniversale(string nuovo) {
 int h = 0, a = 31415, b = 27183;
 for (int i = 0; i < nuovo.length(); i++, a = a*b % (HASH_SIZE - 1))
  h = (a*h + nuovo.at(i)) % HASH_SIZE;
 h = (h < 0) ? (h + HASH_SIZE) : h;
 return h;
}`

cannot seem to get the code tag working sorry

Comment: Well, if your vector is emtpy and you are trying to dereference a value from if by calling hash[key], what you are actually doing is trying to access an position that has not been allocated on the vector. The STL container prevents a buffer overrun by throwing an exception "vector subscript out of range"

Comment: visul studio gives me problem saying that I cannot use nuovo.termine in a lambda expression

Comment: If you need to code your own hash you need to do some validation before accessing you vector. A hash is a non sequential container whereas your vector is sequential (in memory). Perhaps a vector is not the best representation of your hash. Also, if you dont need to have your own hash, consider using std::map.

Comment: That's because the nuovo argument is not in the scope of the lambda. You can simply add the nuovo argument in the lamba's capture list as such [nuovo](const string& str){...}

Comment: ok I made my hash a list instead of a vector with HASH_SIZE=1000 like that: list<Vocabolo> hash[HASH_SIZE];

the code now compiles but it always return me false

Comment: thank you for your help. I figured out how to initialize the vector of lists but I cannot get the insert code to work properly! It works and the compiler doesn't give me warnings but if I insert the same word over and over it always says it was inserted. like it always find the line "bool found = it != this->hash[key].end();" true. Could you help me once more please?